# REGEXP with more than one condition in Google Data Studio?

Tags: regex, case, looker-studio, re2

I’m trying to categorize a custom field like this:

```
CASE
  WHEN REGEXP_MATCH(Campaign, "BLU") THEN "Colour Blue"
  WHEN REGEXP_MATCH(Campaign, "GRE") THEN "Colour Green" 
  WHEN REGEXP_MATCH(Campaign, "CAR") THEN "Product Car"
  WHEN REGEXP_MATCH(Campaign, "MOT") THEN "Product Motorbike"
END
```

It works fine for campaigns with only one “*tag*”, like `MOT` or `GRE`, for example.

I have also campaigns with more than one tag, for example `CAR+GRE`, and the REGEXP only returns the first true condition, in this case, `CAR`. But I’m not able to categorize both, `CAR` and `GRE`.

Comment: Could you elaborate by providing a publicly editable Google Data Studio Report (additionally, a Google Sheet if it's the data set) of the scenario (using sample data that shows 1) Input values (~10 rows) 2) Expected output 3) An attempt at solving the issue)? It would help users visualise the issue and test out suggestions on a specific use case with objective right / wrong answers. Without a [Minimal Reproducible Example](https://stackoverflow.com/help/minimal-reproducible-example) it would be difficult to pinpoint a suggestion and the issue, e.g. Data Set, Data Source, Report, Fields, Chart

Answer (score 1):

Wouldn't it be more sensible to have two dimensions? One for colour and one for product?

You could then do something like:

For colour dimension:

```
… 
WHEN REGEXP_MATCH(Campaign, ".*BLU") THEN "Blue"
WHEN REGEXP_MATCH(Campaign, ".*GRE") THEN "Green"
```

For Product dimension:

```
...
WHEN REGEXP_MATCH(Campaign, "CAR.*") THEN "Car"
WHEN REGEXP_MATCH(Campaign, "MOT.*") THEN "Motorbike"
```

…